# Logic behind a dataframe method having list or a tuple as its input parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a logic behind using a tuple or list as an input mechanism for a dataframe method (or methods in general). In simple words when do we use `df.method()` and when `df.method[]`?

1. Method using list `[]` as an input mechanism

   ```
   df.loc['A']
   ```
2. Method using tuple `()` as an input mechanism

   ```
   df.set_index('A')
   ```

Comment: That's not a list or a tuple, it's indexing vs. calling.

Comment: Right.  `set_index` is a method.  `loc` and `iloc` are variables that act like lists.  There's no way to know from the name.  You have to look at the docs, or try it once and fix it if there is an error.

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with lists or tuples.

Comment: `something[item]` is an indexing operation, `something(item)` is a function call.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html  See first note.  square brackets are an indexing operator as @juanpa.arrivillaga states.

Comment: Thanks all. This really helps!